# Converse of the implication $V(S)\subseteq V(T)\iff T\subseteq\sqrt{\langle S\rangle}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I'm having trouble recalling one direction of the following bi-implication.

Suppose $S,T$ are subsets of the polynomial ring $k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ over an algebraically closed field. We have $V(S)\subseteq V(T)\iff T\subseteq\sqrt{\langle S\rangle}$.

For one direction, I suppose $T\subseteq\sqrt{\langle S\rangle}$. If $f\in T$, then $f^m\in\langle S\rangle$ for some $m$. Let $(a_i)$ be an $n$-tuple in $V(S)=V(\langle S\rangle)$. Then $f^m((a_i))=(f((a_i)))^m=0$, hence $f((a_i))=0$. Then we get $(a_i)\in V(T)$, so $V(S)\subseteq V(T)$.

What's the way to get the other implication? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  implication $\implies$ is false for a non-algebraically closed field, like $\mathbb R$: $\emptyset =V(X^2+1)\subset \emptyset =V(X^2+2)$ but $X^2+2\not\subset \sqrt {(X^2+1)}=(X^2+1)$.
This suggests using the Nullstellensatz, which indeed immediately proves $\implies$ .

Comment: Oh, if $V(S)\subseteq V(T)$, then $IV(S)\supseteq IV(T)$, which by the Nullstellensatz gives $\sqrt{\langle S\rangle}\supseteq\sqrt{S}\supseteq\sqrt{T}\supseteq T$. Thanks Georges.